# sed print line from regex to regex

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file with the following text:

```
text
START
This
has
to
be
printed
STOP
more text
```

Now i want the text in between START and STOP to be printed.
I wrote the following:

```
cat file | sed '/START/,/STOP/p'
```

But that does not seem to be doing what i want. Any suggestions?

Comment: UUOC Award Pending — Useless Use of `cat`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print *between* the start and stop signs, try:

```
sed -n '/START/,/STOP/ { //!p }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
This
has
to
be
printed
```

Comment: Alternatively `sed '/START/,/STOP/!d;//d' file` does the same thing.

Comment: @steve Could you explain the regex '{ //!p }'?

Comment: @user1790040: Thanks. `//!p` can be broken into two bits. `//` means match everything already in the `sed`'s pattern space and `!p` tells `sed` to print everything that doesn't contain the pattern. Another way would be to do: `sed -n '/START/,/STOP/ { /START/n; /STOP/!p }' file.txt`. It's a bit more verbose and would tell `sed` to skip over the line containing 'START' and print everything not containing 'STOP'. HTH.

Answer (score 4):

```
cat file | sed -n '/START/,/STOP/p'
```

-n is needed to supress the default printing of sed.

Comment: `sed` doesn't need to read from `STDIN` so `cat` is not necessary.